# Fill boxes in a 3D grid

Tags: python

I got an array of `n` boxes, where each box has 8 4D coordinates, i.e. a `(x, y, z, l)`, where `(x,y,z)` are the coordinates and `l` is some label, like 'car'

```
boxes.shape = (4, 8, 3, 1)
```

The positions are for example given in meters, and the label is a simple integer. One element of the array could thus look like so:

```
boxes[0]
[
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1], 
    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1], 
    [2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1], 
    [0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1], 
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1], 
    [2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1], 
    [2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1], 
    [0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1]
]
```

I want to sample points (i.e. the `(x,y,z)` coordinates and `labels` separately), every `step_size` meters that are inside the box. For example, I want all points inside the box, that are 0.01 meters apart and add them to a list, with the corresponding amount of labels. I currently use the following approach:

```
mins = np.min(boxes, axis=1)
maxs = np.max(boxes, axis=1)

# collect all new points
sampled_points = []
sampled_labels = []

# get the label for each box
labels = boxes[:, 3]

# distance between each point, equal for all dimensions
step_size = 0.01

# number of points we want to inlcude for each dimension
num_points_x = np.floor((maxs[:, 0] - mins[:, 0]) / step_size).astype(int) 
num_points_y = np.floor((maxs[:, 1] - mins[:, 1]) / step_size).astype(int) 
num_points_z = np.floor((maxs[:, 2] - mins[:, 2]) / step_size).astype(int) 

# loop over all boxes and create the points
for i in range(boxes.shape[0]):
    x_coords, y_coords, z_coords = np.mgrid[mins[i, 0]:maxs[i, 0]:num_points_x[i]*1j, # we use complex number here, so that the endpoint is inlcusive 
                                            mins[i, 1]:maxs[i, 1]:num_points_y[i]*1j, 
                                            mins[i, 2]:maxs[i, 2]:num_points_z[i]*1j]
    points = np.vstack([x_coords.ravel(), y_coords.ravel(), z_coords.ravel()]).T
    labels = np.repeat(labels[i], points.shape[0])

    sampled_points.append(points)
    sampled_labels.append(labels)
```

I am not sure if this is correct and if there is a better way

Comment: Can one assume that all sides of the boxes are parallel to one of the three axes?

Comment: Yes, the boxes are basically cubes (in practice, these boxes are bounding boxes)

Comment: a cube can also have its sides not parallel to the axes. so let's assume for simplicity all edges are parallel to x, y or z axes

Comment: oh sorry, I interpreted your question wrong. Yes, the edges are parallel to either x, y or z. But I am curious how it would work without this condition as well, if you do not mind the effort.

Comment: not sure about the labels part. what should be the label of a point within the box?

Comment: the label inside the box is equal to the label of any corner of the box (they are all the same) if that makes sense. For the sake of simplicity ignore overlaps of boxes.

Comment: so each box has its own label. different edges of the same box can't have different labels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256466/discussion-between-kklaw-and-riccardo-bucco).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `box` is one of your boxes (a NumPy array of shape `(8, 4)`), `label` is the label associated to the box, and assuming `step_size` is a float number, this is how I would find a list of all the points in the box with their label:

```
points = np.mgrid[
    np.min(box[:, 0]):np.max(box[:, 0]):step_size,
    np.min(box[:, 1]):np.max(box[:, 1]):step_size,
    np.min(box[:, 2]):np.max(box[:, 2]):step_size,
    label:label + 1
].reshape(4, -1).T
```

Example:

```
>>> from itertools import product, repeat
>>> import numpy as np
>>> step_size = 0.6
>>> label = 7
>>> box = np.hstack([np.array(list(product(*repeat(range(2), 3)))), np.ones((8,1)) * label])
>>> box
array([[0., 0., 0., 7.],
       [0., 0., 1., 7.],
       [0., 1., 0., 7.],
       [0., 1., 1., 7.],
       [1., 0., 0., 7.],
       [1., 0., 1., 7.],
       [1., 1., 0., 7.],
       [1., 1., 1., 7.]])
>>> points = np.mgrid[
...     np.min(box[:, 0]):np.max(box[:, 0]):step_size,
...     np.min(box[:, 1]):np.max(box[:, 1]):step_size,
...     np.min(box[:, 2]):np.max(box[:, 2]):step_size,
...     label:label + 1
... ].reshape(4, -1).T
>>> points
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 7. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.6, 7. ],
       [0. , 0.6, 0. , 7. ],
       [0. , 0.6, 0.6, 7. ],
       [0.6, 0. , 0. , 7. ],
       [0.6, 0. , 0.6, 7. ],
       [0.6, 0.6, 0. , 7. ],
       [0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 7. ]])
```

Comment: I am curious, how would you do it if the boxes were not axis aligned?

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach seems correct for sampling points inside the boxes, and it utilizes NumPy efficiently. However, there is a minor mistake in your code. You are using labels[i] instead of boxes[i, 0, 0, 3] to get the label for each box.

check this code.

```
mins = np.min(boxes, axis=(1, 2))
maxs = np.max(boxes, axis=(1, 2))

sampled_points = []
sampled_labels = []

step_size = 0.01

for i in range(boxes.shape[0]):
    num_points_x = int(np.floor((maxs[i, 0] - mins[i, 0]) / step_size))
    num_points_y = int(np.floor((maxs[i, 1] - mins[i, 1]) / step_size))
    num_points_z = int(np.floor((maxs[i, 2] - mins[i, 2]) / step_size))

    x_coords, y_coords, z_coords = np.mgrid[mins[i, 0]:maxs[i, 0]:num_points_x * 1j,
                                            mins[i, 1]:maxs[i, 1]:num_points_y * 1j,
                                            mins[i, 2]:maxs[i, 2]:num_points_z * 1j]

    points = np.vstack([x_coords.ravel(), y_coords.ravel(), z_coords.ravel()]).T
    labels = np.repeat(boxes[i, 0, 0, 3], points.shape[0])  # Use boxes[i, 0, 0, 3] instead of labels[i]

    sampled_points.append(points)
    sampled_labels.append(labels)
```